Visual Studio Code configuration for .NET Framework WPF project (VS2019 compatible)
I'm working on some team projects where everyone else uses Visual Studio 2019 Professional, but I prefer Visual Studio Code. We're developing WPF applications using C# .NET Framework. I've created a template project on GitHub to streamline starting new projects.
My .vscode folder currently contains:

settings.json:
{
  "files.exclude": {
      "**/.git": true,
      "**/.vs": true,
      "**/bin": true,
      "**/obj": true
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "csharp.format.enable": true,
  "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never",
  "omnisharp.path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\ManagedLanguages\\VBCSharp\\OmniSharp",
  "omnisharp.useModernNet": false
}


launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug WPF App",
            "type": "clr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/MinimalWpfApp.exe",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        }
    ]
}


tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.com",
            "args": [
                "MinimalWpfApp.sln",
                "/Build",
                "Debug|x64"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "clean",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.com",
            "args": [
                "MinimalWpfApp.sln",
                "/Clean",
                "Debug|x64"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ]
        }
    ]
}



However, when I open the project in VS Code, I get the following warnings and errors:
[warning] The project file 'path\to\minimal-wpf-vs2019\MinimalWpfApp.csproj' is in unsupported format (for example, a traditional .NET Framework project). It need be converted to new SDK style to work in C# Dev Kit.
[error] Failed to load project 'path\to\minimal-wpf-vs2019\MinimalWpfApp.csproj'. One or more errors occurred. (This project is not supported in C# Dev Kit.)
[info] Project system initialization finished. 0 project(s) are loaded, and 1 failed to load.

Additionally, VS Code extensions keep trying to use tools from C:\Program Files\dotnet\, which I need to keep for other projects.
What are the canonical VS Code configuration files (settings.json, launch.json, tasks.json, etc.) for developing a C# .NET Framework WPF project in Visual Studio Code while maintaining compatibility with team members using Visual Studio 2019 Professional?
I'm looking for a configuration that:

Uses Visual Studio 2019's compiler (i.e., devenv.com) and tools exclusively.
Avoids conflicts with .NET Core/.NET 5+ tooling.
Provides a smooth development experience in VS Code (intellisense, debugging, etc.).
Maintains project compatibility with Visual Studio 2019 for my team members.


Why can't you use Visual Studio, if you're the only one? Why you don't align with the standard and make things harder for yourself :)

@MichałTurczyn I prefer VSCode. I use it for everything else. I am more comfortable with the UI, the settings, the environment. And if it is freemium/FLOSS. It is extendible. It has a huge community. It is cross platform... I could go on.

@MichałTurczyn I use both. I prefer VS for .NET projects because I know how to use it for .NET projects, through long experience before VSC existed. To switch, I'd have to figure out what extensions to install, adjust keyboard shortcuts, etc., etc. (in short, to answer this question). I find the VS debugging experience far superior. Maybe there are extensions I could install that would reduce the difference, but why bother? I have VS and I like it. For a developer who knows and likes VSC, it's another matter entirely. VS has a significant learning curve. Why bother? This is a great question.

You use C# Dev Kit within VSC? That should actually solve some of the compatibility problems. Beyond that trying to do something in "compatibility" mode to get what you want to make your life easier may make life for everyone else on the team harder. Being homogeneous in the tool chain within a team normally make life for everyone easier. You don't need to solve those extra "compatibility" problems and concentrate more on the actual product(s).

Imo you should just us visual studio,. VS is fully compatible has a designer and your team won't hate you for messing their projects up.

I opened the project you uploaded to Github as a folder, configured the command property of your tasks.json to my devenv.com path, configured RUN AND DEBUG to Debug WPF App (name property of your launch.json) by pressing Ctrl+Shift+D, and then ran it by pressing F5. The project ran successfully without the error you mentioned. (My EXTENSIONS installed .NET Install Tool, C#, C# Dev Kit)

I also don't recommend you to write WPF programs in VSCode. In addition to the above-mentioned problems, EXTENSIONS has little support for WPF programs. When you write XAML in VSCode, you may not be able to observe the XAML generated page in real time. In addition, when you want to create a new XAML, there may be no corresponding Template, which will increase your workload.
